# get selected file in CkEditor & add custom upload button

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor, angular5

1. i am using ngx-ckeditor: "0.4.0" in angular 5.
2. i want upload image & add custom upload button
3. below is my html.

   ```
   <ck-editor 
             #ckeditor 
             name="html_template" 
             [(ngModel)]="mailModel.html_template" 
             [config]="ckEditorConfig">
   </ck-editor>
   ```
4. here is my component code.

   ```
   this.ckEditorConfig = {
      filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/application/crm/distribution-list/create-mail',
      filebrowserUploadUrl : 'http://192.168.0.107:8000/api/crm/v1.0/crm-distribution-library-files',
      fileTools_requestHeaders :{
         'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
         Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
      },
      filebrowserUploadMethod : 'xhr',
      removeButtons: 'Forms,Iframe,Blocks,Subscript,Superscript,Maximize,Undo',
   };
   ```
5. with this code i am not able to get image & can't pass my custom header.

> **i want to get selected image & add custom 'Upload Image' button.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below is the code for add custom button in CkEditor

```
@ViewChild('ckeditor') ckeditor: CKEditorComponent;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this._addImageUploadBtn();
}

_addImageUploadBtn() {
    const editor = this.ckeditor && this.ckeditor.instance;
    if (!editor) {
      return;
    }
    var that = this;
    editor.ui.addButton('uploadImage', {
        icon: 'https://img.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/image.png',
        label: 'Upload Image',
        command: 'uploadImage',
        toolbar: 'insert'
      });
    editor.addCommand('uploadImage', {
      exec: function(editor: any) {
        // Remove img input.
        [].slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll('.ck-editor-upload-img')).forEach((img: any) => {
          img.remove();
        });
        const input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute('type', 'file');
        input.setAttribute('class', 'ck-editor-upload-img');
        input.style.display = 'none';
        input.addEventListener('change', e => {
            const file = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).files[0];
            if (file) {
               console.log(file);
               // Do Stuff
            }
          },
          false
        );
        document.body.appendChild(input);
        input.click();
      }
    });
  }
```

> here you get the selected image file, and also get custom button click.